# Can I replace a socket based protocol with gRPC?

Tags: grpc

I’m researching options to upgrade a legacy TCP socket protocol where either end can initiate messages/transactions and am intrigued by gRPC as an option.

My criteria are:

- supports authentication
- layer 7 (vs layer 4 for current implementation)
- supports TLS

From what I’ve read so far, gRPC has all this. However, it’s not clear to me that it has  peer-peer capabilities. The behavior I’m interested in is:

1. client can request info and send commands to server (supported)
2. server can send updates to client on its own initiative (supported)
3. #1 can happen while #2 is happening

It seems to me that defining a server stream for case #2 would work. It’d basically be a

```
// use case 2
rpc SubscribeToEvents(EventsSubscriptionRequest) returns (stream EventDescriptor);
```

But would I also be able to use case #1 while #2 was active?

```
// use case 1
rpc GetValue(ValueRequest) returns (ValueResponse);
```

Thanks in advance for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use a multi-threaded implementation, it's possible for both #1 and #2 concurrently.

However, you describe a client-server scenario not peer-peer; the client must initiate both #1 (unary) and #2 (streaming) RPCs.

True peer-peer would have the endpoints implement client **and** server such that either peer could initiate (unary and|or streaming) RPCs against another.

Answer (score 0):

You could have both sides be both client and server, as the other answer suggests.  But if you are okay with having the client be the one to initiate the connection and the stream, you could use a single bidirectional stream between the two sides.  Once the client initiates the stream, the client and server can each send messages on the stream whenever they want to.